# Annual Inflation Rate Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question has me stumped. Anyone have ideas to point me in the right direction of a quick and easy way to solve this? I took this from a practice GRE subject math test and each problem is only suppose to take 2.5 minutes to solve.

**At a 15 percent annual inflation rate, the value of the dollar would decrease by approximately one-half every 5 years. At this inflation rate, how many years would the dollar be worth one millionth of its present value?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V$ as initial value of the dollar, decreases approximately one half: $V_{n+1}\approx\frac{1}{2}V_n$ every $5$ years.

$V$ at first.

 $\frac{1}{2}V$ after $5$ years.

 $\frac{1}{4}V$ after $10$ years.

 $\dots$

After $5n$ years:

$$ V\approx\frac{1}{2^{n}}V_0$$

Now for one-millionth solve:

$1/2^n=1/1000000$

$2^n=1000000$

$n\approx19.9316$

Thus the answer is after $\approx100$ years which is a rough rounded estimate.

Comment: Is there any easy way to see this without the use of a calculator (as you aren't allowed one for the exam)

Answer (score 3):

If annual inflation is 15%, then something that costs \$1 today will cost \$1.15 one year from today.

In five years it will cost \$$(1.15)^5$ which is about \$2.01.

You need to solve $(1.15)^n = 1000000$ for $n$. After $n$ years, something that costs one dollar will cost one million dollars.

The correct answer is $n = \dfrac{\log 1000000}{\log 1.15} \approx 98.85$.